# Decimal order of addition affects results

Tags: c#, math, decimal

I have a system that is performing lots of calculations using decimals, occasionally it will add up the same numbers, but return different results, +/- 0.000000000000000000000000001

Here is a short example:

```
decimal a = 2.016879990455473621256359079m;
decimal b = 0.8401819425625631128956517177m;
decimal c = 0.4507062854741283043456903406m;
decimal d = 6.7922317815078349615022988627m;

decimal result1 = a + b + c + d;
decimal result2 = a + d + c + b;

Console.WriteLine((result1 == result2) ? "Same" : "DIFFERENT");
Console.WriteLine(result1);
Console.WriteLine(result2);
```

That outputs:

```
DIFFERENT
10.100000000000000000000000000
10.100000000000000000000000001
```

The differences are so small that there is no practical effect, but has anyone seen something like this before? I expected that when adding up the same numbers you would always get the same results.

Comment: This is the single most common recurring question at StackOverflow.

Comment: google floating point inexact representation, read wikipedia on it or search SO :)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `decimal` data-type is supposed to be immune to round-off errors.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Will A - No. That is simply not true. ANY floating point approximation with a finite number of digits may suffer from roundoff errors.

Comment: @woodchips: you might add, because any floating point representation with a finite number of places requires rounding in certain calculations.

Comment: @Andreas I beg to differ, I'm sure the "how do I fake input" questions are more voluminous!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The entire field of [Numerical analysis](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Numerical_analysis) is devoted to studying these kind of effects and how to avoid them.

To produce the best result when summing a list of floating point numbers, first *sort* the list from smallest to largest, and add them up in that order.

Comment: Since he is using decimal (as opposed to a floating point number), isn't this a bit of a different issue?

Comment: @Mark, `decimal` _is_ a floating-point number, but with different numbers of bits allocated for the mantissa vs the exponent to provide a better tool for handling currency. `double` will typically have just 14 digits of precision, which is right at the edge of sufficient mantissa to represent e.g. US deficit accurate to hundredths-of-a-dollar. `decimal` can represent more than twice as many digits, but at the expense of a much smaller overall range due to the smaller exponent.

Comment: @sarnold:  Thanks for the info.  I didn't realize that the decimal type in .net was implemented as a floating point value.  I was thinking (for no particular reason) it would be implemented underneath more along the lines of some kind of BCD arithmetic.

Comment: @Mark, I initially assumed the same until I read the [spec (4.1.7)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) :) Alas, they made a tradeoff for speed and size and hoped 28 digits was good enough for everybody. :)

Comment: Thanks! I implemented a kind of sorting so that at least most of the time the numbers will be added in the same order

Comment: @Mark, sarnold: Decimal is encoded using base 10. Double is encoded using base 2. Both are floating-point formats. The fact that Decimal is a floating point type is due to its definition; that's not  an implementation detail. Even if it were implemented using bcd, it would be a floating point type and subject to rounding errors. Also, double always has the same precision, not "typically 14 digits". The precision may seem to vary because it is an exact number of bits, which translates inexactly to (decimal) digits.

Comment: In the real world (well, my version of it), nobody doing numerical analysis sorts numbers before summing them.

Answer (score 3):

You might suspect a `decimal` type to be immune to the bane of `double`-users everywhere.

But [because `decimal` has 28-29 digits of precision](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and your input is asking for the sum of 29 digits of precision of data, you're right at the very edge of what your data type can accurately represent.

Answer (score 3):

Read [The Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/), [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), and of course [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf). Ah, also [How to mess with people who’ve learned to expect rounding errors in floating-point math.](http://floating-point-gui.de/xkcd/).

Answer (score 2):

According [to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx), the precision of a decimal is 28-29 digits.  At least one of your numbers is 29 digits, so you are likely exceeding the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Because of rounding the result of sum for multiple numbers may vary depending upon the order in which they are summed. This won't happen in mathematics but the way sum is computed in your example the order matters. `result += number;` sums and stores the result in result variable. At that time some of the precision is lost. However, if we do it in the same order, it would always result in same result.

```
Console.WriteLine(numbers.Sum()); // Always returns 9.214085249270111332166335344
```

Because of this many programs use Bankers rounding which produces closer results. Please know the precision is always lost. There is no way to store "accurate" floating point number in compuiter memor

[Rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding)

[Bankers Rounding](http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/i_BankersRounding.htm)